# EXC_BAD_ACCESS: When calling Nan::Callback

Tags: c++, node.js, callback, v8, node.js-addon

I am writing a Node.js c++ addon which requires frequent callbacks from C++ to Javascript.

The constructor requires two functions, an success and an error callback.

```
...
// assuming info[0] and info[1] are functions with ->IsFunction()
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
myClass->Wrap(info.Holder());
myClass->onStateUpdateCallback = new Nan::Callback(info[0].As<v8::Function>());
myClass->onErrorCallback = new Nan::Callback(info[1].As<v8::Function>());
...
```

`onStateUpdateCallback` and `onErrorCallback` are both private properties of the class MyClass defined like this:

```
...
Nan::Callback* onStateUpdateCallback;
Nan::Callback* onErrorCallback;
...
```

Now when I call the `onStateUpdateCallback` from another function it works the first time, but fails the second time by throwing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (while debugging via `lldb`).

Thats how I call the callback (**Note: The function gets called from an external library that executes the calls in different threads, the first time in the main thread, the second time in thread #13, which may cause the problem!**):

```
...
const int argc = 4;
// The arguments should be numbers and strings, but I simplified it to null...
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] = {
    Nan::Null(),
    Nan::Null(),
    Nan::Null(),
    Nan::Null()
};
onStateUpdateCallback->Call(argc, argv);
...
```

I assume that the function or the scope has been garbage collected by Javascript, but I have no idea how to prevent this behaviour, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Something outside of the code sections you've posted is the likely culprit. `Nan::Callback`s are persistent (do not allow GC of the wrapped function).

Comment: Side note: highly recommend defining `class MyClass { Nan::Callback onStateUpdateCallback; }` and using `myClass.onStateUpdateCallback.Reset(info[0].As<v8::Function>())` so you get RAII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have thought, there was an issue with different threads.

I fixt the threading issue by using `Nan::AsyncProgressWorker`.

Comment: Where did you add Nan::AsyncProgressWorker?

Comment: @bmacnaughton I basically took the binding class and moved it to its own class that inherits from `Nan::AsyncProgressWorker`. The binding class initializes and starts the binding class.